# Is it possible to use present and past in one sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, british-english, literature, literary-english

> In *On The Road* Jack admits to Justin W. Brierly that he loves Neal Cassady because he reminds him of his brother, Gerard, who dies when Jack was five years old.

Is this grammatical?
The first part of the sentence is in the present whereas the other in the past!!

Comment: A book or film review, like a newspaper story, often uses the present tense, but as you see can run into trouble... "who **died** when Jack was five years old."

Comment: Is that a direct quote or are you just paraphrasing? You should probably provide an actual quotation along with a link. (Otherwise, anything here is speculation without context.)

Comment: It should either be *who dies when Jack is five years old* or *who died when Jack was five years old*. The combination of the two doesn't work.

Comment: I believe, as with the answer given, that it should be: *Jack admits he loves NC because he reminds him of his brother who died when Jack was five years old*.

Comment: @manal Please don't remove relevant material from your question. However, **all** the verbs in the quote are present-tense, so you may need to provide a better example.

Answer (score 2):

The reason reviews use the present tense is because it is the technically correct way to talk about events in a given *fictional* story.  Since the story exists in the present, so do its characters and their actions.

When an element is referred to in the past tense, it suggests either that the story talks about actual events and people, or that something happened outside the events that actively take place within the story.

Alternatively, if you are discussing non-fiction (such as political reporting or history), using the present tense strongly implies skepticism regarding the accuracy or integrity of the author.

As for your example, I would guess that "*had died* when Jack *was* five years old" (past perfect *had died* is better here than *died*) is the correct way to phrase it, since it does not seem like Jack being five or his brother dying actually takes place within the story's timeline. The event is part of the character's own backstory, and the past tense is descriptive - not active - in relation to the story.

Comment: Good point but surely the opposite conclusion, because "something happened outside the events that actively take place within the story". Jack is not 5 years old, he is on the road. So Gerard **died**, before the time of the story.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ah, yes, that is what I meant to say.  Thanks! :)

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree with you. If the film started with Jack's brother dying and then sped forward you could make a case for the present tense, but even that sounds odd to me. However if the film started with Jack and his brother going out on the town and his brother being killed then  I think I would use the present tense in the review since the death is an integral part of the story line.

Comment: @BoldBen I agree with both of you, I typed the original one by mistake.  I also wrote "his mother" instead of "his brother" for no reason, which I just corrected too.  Not enough coffee or something.  Or perhaps too much.

Comment: @MishaR Sorry for my comment, I didn't see yours until I'd posted mine!

Comment: @ManalMoumni I can't really speak for your supervisor, so not really sure what her/his preference is in regards to the paper. I can only tell you what the general rules are. If you are talking about something that happens in the story, use present. If the past is part of a character's background, but didn't happen in the story, use past (as in, "he speaks about his brother, who had died when he was five"). When referring to the author's actual life, use past (with the exception of the author's actually writing the story, in which case you want to say "he writes about," not "he wrote about").

Comment: @ManalMoumni Ultimately, this is something you might want to clear up with your supervisor.

Comment: @BoldBen No prob. If it wasn't for your comment, I wouldn't have noticed that I wrote "mother" instead of "brother." :)